# Returning multiple models in a list to one view

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, restsharp

I am having an issue returning multiple models in one view.  I have a model that has a collection of other models. So when I return the model (ProblemsVM) that has the collection of the other 2, I would like to attach the other 2 to the model being returned so I can access it's values in the view.  Any help will be greatly appreciated and thank you for taking your time to read.

This is my ProblemsVM model and the 2 IEnumerables that I want to include in the views return.

```
public class ProblemsVM
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Type> Types {get; set;}
    }
```

This is the action returning the view I want to attach the 2 models to. Right now it populates a table of different problems by ProjectId that it receives from the API.

```
public ActionResult ReturnProblems()
    {
       List<ProblemsVM> dv = new List<ProblemsVM>();

       // return problems
       var requestDef = new RestRequest("problem", Method.GET);
       requestDef.AddHeader("id", userId);
       requestDef.AddHeader("key", userKey);
       requestDef.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
       var responseDef = Userclient.Execute(requestDef) as RestResponse;

       List<ProblemsVM> problems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ProblemsVM>>(responseDef.Content);
       IEnumerable<ProblemsVM> problemsToReturn = problems.Where(d => d.ProjectId == item.ProjectId);

       return View(problemsToReturn);

    }
```

So what I am looking to do would be something like this that I have in another application. In this one it works fine when using a Model not in a list or `IEnumerable`.  I am having trouble switching this over to the above method to be returned with the list of problems.  ProbVM is the same as ProblemsVM in the other project.

```
ProbVM tt = new ProbVM();
   tt.Cats = db.Categories.ToList();
   tt.Typ = db.Types.ToList();
return View(tt);
```

This is my other 2 models that are stored in the SQL database:

```
    public partial class Type
        {

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public int Order { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public int CategoryId { get; set; }

            public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        }

    public partial class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            this.Types = new HashSet<Type>();
            this.Companys = new HashSet<Company>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int CompanyId { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Company> Companys { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Type> Types { get; set; }
    }
```

-----UPDATED PART------

So when this button(which is in the rows of the datatables) is clicked it pops up a modal:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Type", "Problem", new { id = item.Id })" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" role="button" id="launch">Type</a>
```

and on the button id "launch" is called in ajax by:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#type-modal").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 600,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            open: function () {
                $("#accordion").accordion({ autoHeight: true });
            }
        });
        $(".launch").click(function () {
            Id.value = $(this).attr('value');
            $("#type-modal").dialog("open");
        })
    });
</script>
```

and in the type-modal div is where I will use the Category and Type model to use razor(would like to use something like this like I did in the other project):

```
foreach (var item in Model.Cats)
        {
            @Html.Label(item.Title, new { cats = item.Title })<br/>
            foreach(var tri in Model.types)
            {
                if (item.CategoryId == tri.CategoryId)
                { 
                @Html.RadioButton(tri.Category.Title, tri.Order)
                @Html.Label(tri.Description)<br/>
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: It might help if you mentioned what exactly the "problem" you keep running into is.

Comment: So my problem is that if it was a model that was not a list i could just do problemsToReturn.Categories.  But since it is not and it is a List whenever I do the . after problemsToReturn it just bring up the options of stuff like Where and Any and does not let me choose a model to add.  So I am trying to figure out how to add the 2 models inside ProblemsVM to that problemsToReturn like I did in the last example.

Comment: I don't think you are fully thinking about the problem.  Your previous situation only had one ProblemVM.  Now, you can have an arbitrary number.  How do you know which ProblemVM in the list goes with which set of models?  There doesn't appear to be any way to distinguish that information.

Comment: So my goal is that a whole list of problems is sent back to the view as of now and displayed in a data table.  Each row will have a button on it that when clicked it will pop up a modal which is where I will use the Category and Type models that are linked through the ProblemsVM model.  So the ProblemVM is being used to display the razor data on the view itself, while the other 2 models will be used to display their razor in the modal.  Am I on the right track, getting used to this stuff sorry lol.

Comment: What do you mean you will "use" the category and type?  How will you "use" them?  You don't appear to have any way to choose a selected Category or type in your models.  Are these the same for every ProblemVM?  If so why do a database lookup repeatedly for the same data?  This is all just a very poor way to do it.  Or maybe you populate category and type from another set of data?  But then your working example makes no sense because you have no discriminators.

Comment: Your problem seems to be that you're trying to merge data from two different sources, a set of Json data, presumably posted to the action, and data from a database.  This is a more complex linq scenario.  This isn't going to scale well.  Imagine if there are 100 ProblemVM's.  That means you need to do at least 200 database lookups, which will take forever.

Comment: That's it lol(the more complex linq scenario).  That Json data is being stored in the ProblemsVM (which is displayed the list in the table) and the Category and Type are models in the sql tables. Ill update the question maybe it will help to understand more.